# Enable CheckBoxes after Radio Button is selected

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Im working with SharedPreferences/Settings where I want to have two radiobuttons. When one of the radiobuttons is selected, it should enable a list of checkboxes and disable the checkboxes under the other radiobutton. Any idea how to approach this? thanks! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)**, get value and enable checkbox using `yourchestbox.setEnabled(true);`